# where can I check the documentation of prometheus metric

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus

In the Kubernetes environment, I'm using Prometheus.

And there, I can view lots of metrics such as **kube_node_status_allocatable,  kube_resourcequota,...**

I want to know what this metric means. But I can't find any documentation about it.
In the repo of Kubernetes, I found this page. https://github.com/kubernetes/kube-state-metrics/blob/main/docs/resourcequota-metrics.md
But the explanation is too short.

I want to know where can I check the official documentation about it.
I want to figure out what the type means in **kube_resourcequota** metric.

I already checked prometheus homepages. But It can't be found.
Do I have to dig the source codes?

Answer (score 0):

do you mean what is resource quota?
https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/policy/resource-quotas/
You'll find kube_resourcequota is same as `kubectl get resourcequotas -A`.